# Docker secret protection in sharing environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have read docker secret alot article. Is there a way the secret file in an encrypted mode. The server I will be sharing with multiple people and I plan push the secret file to source code version control. How I can protect it by encryption and only docker can view if they have the key . O using docker compose

Comment: Anyone who can run any `docker` command has unrestricted root-level access to the whole host; they can mount any Docker secret or volume or host directory they want.  If it's a multi-user system, you may need to carefully restrict who can run Docker commands, or require `sudo` access to use Docker.

Comment: Is there something like vault like ansible it encrypt and somewhere to store password to decrypt the file